# Is ".git" at end of repository name important in local git repository, remote repository location?

Tags: git, git-remote

I just realised all this time, I was using `https://github.com/userName/repoName` to set the remote location for a local repository in git. But, everywhere it is used with **.git** suffix as `https://github.com/userName/repoName.git` to set the remote. I believe .git is used to indicate that the location is a git (version controlled) repository.

But, does it really matter, if I had ignored the `.git` all this time. Should I modify the remote of my local repositories?

Personally, I didn't face any issues till now. So I guess, it is just a naming convention sort of thing, and don't have to be concerned much about this.

Comment: https://github.community/t/url-used-to-clone-a-repo-through-git/1306

Comment: `But, everywhere it is used with .git suffix as https://github.com/userName/repoName.git to set the remote` - how is that? Do you realize you can do just `https://github.com/userName/repoName`?

Comment: Questions with the word "should" are not a good fit for Stack Overflow (you can't get from "is" to "ought", as Hume would say). Personally, I would say yes, it's better to use the `.git` suffix, because that is how Git works; the `.git` file is the repo. It just happens that GitHub has a feature where it compensates for you if you omit the suffix, but that doesn't make it right to omit it. Omitting it is a bad habit because other remote repositories might not be so charitable.

Comment: the `path-to-repo.git` path is normally used for _bare_ repos.... but it certainly is a convention, not a mandate.

Comment: Git talks to the remote server and endpoint identified by the url you set for the remote. Exactly what the *server* does with your request depends on the server. While it might not matter to github, in the sense that they will serve on the git protocol even to an url without the .git at the end, other hosting services might not be so lenient. So, since you haven't tagged your question as github only, the correct answer here is "it depends".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my own mild surprise, I think this is an answerable question.

> But, does it really matter, if I had ignored the .git all this time. Should I modify the remote of my local repositories?

Your remotes point to GitHub, and their service apparently won't 404 a url that doesn't end `.git` without checking whether it would have worked with `.git` appended. So for your local repositories, there is no practical reason for you to change your remotes' urls: they work. No, it doesn't really matter. For those urls. Because GitHub understands what you're trying to do.